# Why does defining an implicit function as an object property work in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: javascript

How does this even work on Firefox and Chrome, but error on IE. As far as I can see, this should always produce an error, but somehow Firefox and Chrome allow you to do this.

Is this actually a part of one of the ES standards or is this just some weirdness.

```
var Greeter = {
   sayHi( name )
   {
      alert( name );
   }
};

Greeter.sayHi( 'kevin' );
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using [ES6 syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015).

For using the object with ES5, you could use a [function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) instead.

```js
var Greeter = {
        sayHi: function(name) {
            alert(name);
        }
    };

Greeter.sayHi('kevin');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is ES2015 (aka "ES6"): It's the new method syntax.

It doesn't work in IE because IE doesn't support it, having been released years before the ES2015 spec was completed. It would work just fine in Edge.

Comment: the destruction of javascript has finally entered the execution stage